# I need to find $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{(2a^3 x - x^4)^{1/2} - a(a - x)^{1/3}}{a - (ax^3)^{1/4}}$ where $a > 0$

Tags: calculus

It's been a while since I've had to explicitly manipulate something this complicated, and I'm having a hard time doing it.

Comment: Use the formula $\lim\limits _{x\to a} \dfrac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the powers of x in the numerator and the denominator, it is reasonable to assume that numerator goes to 0 faster than the denominator. That intuition says that the limit is 0. Use LHospital's rule to show that the limit is 0.

Comment: I understand the idea behind it, however I am not strong enough with calculus to explicitly work through this.

Comment: If you are not comfortable differentiating the numerator or the denominator of the function, it is good to learn the calculus techniques. That will enable to evaluate these kind of limits easily and quickly. For more details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: I am comfortable differentiating the numerator and denominator; however, this problem requires a great deal of derivatives and manipulation of long strings of characters that I am not comfortable doing as a result of a disability; this is why I asked for an explicit solution.

Comment: Show your attempt here and we can sort it out! :)